# Placing a button at the bottom of the page and bottom of a list

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a button anchored to the bottom of the view and also bottom of the list if the list gets bigger than the view.

So I want them to look like this when list is smaller than screen:

[image]

and like this when bigger:

[image][image]

I know I should use `RelativeLayout` to place the button at the bottom of the page with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` but when I also add `android:layout_below="@id/table_wrapper"` my button's height will get messed up if content is smaller than view:

[image]

Is there anyone who know how I can accomplish this?

The simplified version of my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/book_layout_whole"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/table_wrapper"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/vertical_header_table"
                        android:layout_width="85dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:text="Day"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    <View
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#444444"></View>
                    <View
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#444444"></View>
                    <View
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#444444"></View>
                    <View
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#444444"></View>
                    <View
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#444444"></View>
                    <View
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#444444"></View>
                    <View
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:background="#444444"></View>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <Button
                    android:text="load more"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/table_wrapper"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Note 1:

removing `android:layout_below="@id/table_wrapper"` will result in the button always being at the bottom of the screen, even when there list is bigger than the screen.

### Note 2

Adding `layout_weight` would not work, because the size of my view is dynamic.

Comment: the TextView should be aligned with the view ??

Comment: What do you mean by aligned with view? the reason for the two LinearLayouts is to create the effect of header (text view) with some icons coming in the gray area

Comment: just thought that would be better to use a listview...

Comment: I can't use ListView because for the icons I'm capturing swipe gesture and scrolling populating the data dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use following, it will **surely help you**, i have tested it !

```
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/table_wrapper" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="load more" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This will result in the button always being at the bottom of the screen, even when there list is bigger than the screen.

Comment: hmm :) @maclir test and let me know whats the result ?

Comment: Thanks a lot :D it worked :) Dont know why I never thought of this solution...  I was struggling with this for a long time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why my post was deleted By George Stocker

Check it maclir should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/book_layout_whole"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/table_wrapper"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/vertical_header_table"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Day" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Day" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Day" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Day" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Day" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Day" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Day" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#444444" >
                    </View>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#444444" >
                    </View>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#444444" >
                    </View>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#444444" >
                    </View>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#444444" >
                    </View>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#444444" >
                    </View>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="#444444" >
                    </View>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5.5"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:text="load more" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Adding layout_weight would not work, because the size of my view is dynamic.

Comment: This would not have any effect since layout_height has to be set to 0dp. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3996104/1432239

Comment: Like Knight Comented:"Yeah, no need of 0PX. I am referring Android For Programmers book from Dietel, they also don't use that 0px",

Comment: And I'm just using the weight to place the Button to the bottom

Comment: If you insist on using 0dp as height just change the weight of the linear layout of the Button with the table wrapper.

Comment: The answer form Tarsem is working for me. Your answer seems to be working as well, but I don't understand it... Can you explain how it works?